# Two Dimensional ArrayList Java (Gui)

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I am trying to create program that holds the details of various instruments (e.g. guitars, keyboards). I want it to have information on each item in the Arraylist. I want each instrument to have a Manufacturer and a "description". I am not new to 2D arrays, however i do not know how to use it in Array lists.
I have given it an attempt. (Ps i need to be able to access all of these things to be able to put into a gui. I hope that made sense.)

```
public class Main {

    public static Login form = new Login();
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> instt = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    public static ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        row.add("Chelo");
        row.add("Drums");
        row.add("Flute");
        row.add("Guitar");
        row.add("Harp");
        row.add("Piano");
        row.add("Recorder");
        row.add("Trombone");
        row.add("Trumpet");
        row.add("Xylophone");
        instt.add(row);

        form.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to create an Instrument-Class containing all your information.

```
public static ArrayList<Instrument> row = new ArrayList<Instrument>();

public static void main(String[] args){
    row.add(new Instrument("Guitar","Stackoverflow-Instruments","Best guitar!!"));
    row.add(new Instrument("Piano","Stackoverflow-Instruments","Best piano!!"));
}

public static class Instrument{
    private String name;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Instrument(String name, String manufacturer, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i am so confused on what you have done here. Also it comes up with an error (specifically the row.add(new Instrument("Guitar","Stackoverflow-Instruments","Best guitar!!")); bit) it says that not static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: I've updated the post. This error came up since the Instrument is an inner-class and was not  declared static. You could have fixed the issue by defining Instrument as an outer-class (which is actually the better approach).

Comment: Thank you , this has really helped. One final question.  How do i access the information separately. In my GUI, i have a separate box for Description and manufacture etc. How can i code it so it gets what ive written in there (e.g "Best Guitar!!" ) and only put that in the description. Thank you.

Comment: By using the defined getters. For example 'row.get(0).getDescription();'